# Why console is showing templates not defined error in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django , I am facing one while django running server , I have copy and paste my code please tell me what is wrong with my code

```
'DIRS': [templates],
NameError: name 'templates' is not defined
```

in settings.py file , I have put templates in [] brackets

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [templates],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

this is my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(response):
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

this is urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

templates should be string. so ['templates'] instead of [templates]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change **DIRS** here

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Here, Django expects it has a template path but you provide `templates` variable which does not have any path.

Answer (score 1):

While others have already given right answers on *how to fix it*, but I would like to point out a minor thing that you are getting the `NameError` because you haven't defined the name `templates`.

The `NameError` is raised when the variable you are using is not defined anywhere in the program (if you defined it outside the current scope you will be getting `UnboundLocalError`).

If you define the name templates as a string for the absolute path to your template folder, this will work. Still, never use absolute path in your Django application cause it will become a headache while deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your line to this

```py
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

In the begging of the settings files you can see the BASE_DIR

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Changing DIRS to

```py
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Will help the app to find the templates folder.
Just a personal advice in each app store the templates/appname folder for the specific app. It will help you to have a more robust Django app.

for example you have the polls app, inside the polls app it will be like this

pollsApp/templates/pollsApp/index.html etc.

Also [here is the official guide, it might help you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this
'DIRS': [templates],
with this
'DIRS': ["templates"],